# Angularjs using Spring MVC RESTful Web service

Tags: json, angularjs, rest, spring-mvc, get

I am new to angularjs and resently began to try consuming RESTful web services with angularjs.
In my Spring MVC application I have a controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/exam/{examName}")
public class SomeController {

    @Autowired
    private QuestionService questionService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{examId}", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getExam(@PathVariable int examId) {

        List<Question> questions = questionService.find(Question.class, "examId", examId);

        return JSONUtil.convertObjectToJSON(questions); //A json array is returned
    }

}
```

This controller returnes following JSON array:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "examId": 2,
        "text": "1. Eyniköklü sözlər cərgəsini müəyyənləşdirin.\r\n"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "examId": 2,
        "text": "2. Sait səslərə aid düzgün fikiriəri seçin.\r\n\n\n\n\n\n1. Hava axını ağız boşluğunda heç bir maneəyə rast gəlmir.\r\n"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "examId": 2,
        "text": "3. Asılı tərəfi əsl Azərbaycan sözü ilə ifadə olunmuş söz birləşmələrini göstərin.\r\n"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "examId": 2,
        "text": "4. \"Amma sən lap ağ elədin ha\" cümləsində köməkçi nitq hissələrini ardıcıllıqla göstərin.\r\n"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "examId": 2,
        "text": "5. Hansı söz birləşməsinin asılı tərəfi aşağıdakı sxemə uyğundur?\r\n"
    }
]
```

And here is my html file, that consumes this web service with angularjs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-controller="customersController"> 
  <div ng-repeat="x in names">
    {{ x.text }} <br>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function customersController($scope,$http) {
  $http.get("http://localhost:8086/QuizNoqteAz/exam/abituriyent/2")
  .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response;});
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The web service works correctly, I have tested it with Postman Rest Client. Angular js isn't working. The html file produces a blank page and nothing is shown.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried defining a module to store the controller in?

Comment: I am new to angularjs and didn't use modules yet. The method that I use here is described in w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_customers_json
And I just don't get why my json is not parsed by angularjs.

Comment: You could try doing a `console.log(response)` inside the `$http.get` to see what's actually being returned.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8086/QuizNoqteAz/exam/abituriyent/2. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: The question is, why from my local I can parse w3schools's JSON (I have created the same html file as in above link), but not my webservice's?

Comment: You have to enable CORS (Cross Origin Requests) on your Spring MVC. Here's a guide: http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: Please, add your comment as an answer, I want to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see what's wrong you can output the response to the console by using `console.log(response)` and look in the browser's console. This will tell you what is being returned from the server.

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

is because of CORS is not enabled for the server. [This](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) guide will tell you how to do it.